# Dispatch form data to thunk results in 'breaking the rules of hooks' error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, dispatch, thunk

This is a simple task, but I'm doing something wrong and don't know how to do it right. Help is appreciated.

All I need to do is dispatch some form data to a thunk. The thunk has useSelector() in it, and I've built four or five slices similar with no problem. But this time I am 'breaking the rules of hooks', which I think I understand, but I don't know how to fix the problem and complete the task.

**Here is some code**

shippingInfo.js:

This function is called from the form's onSubmit (in a component named ShippingInfoDisplay.js). It dispatches 'saveAddress', which lives in the thunk:

```
   function handleSaveShippingInfo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // many form fields taken from e.target and assigned to variables
   
        dispatch(saveAddress({ list of form variables })); // <<< this crashes the thunk. 'breaking the rules of hooks'
    }
```

Here are the first few lines of the 'saveAddress' thunk. It breaks when trying to get a token using a selector:

addressSlice.js:

```
export const saveAddress = createAsyncThunk (
    'addresses/saveAddress',
    async ( props, thunkAPI ) => {
        const { list of form variables  } = props;     
        let theApiUrl = API_BASE_URL + '/api/v1/address'
        authToken = useSelector(selectJwtToken) // <<< 'breaking rules of hooks' error
```

Most likely I am the source of the problem, since I don't yet understand hooks well enough. So far I understand that another piece is needed to fix the problem, but I don't know what that piece is. My best guess is that the dispatch to 'saveAddress' needs to be outside of the 'handleSaveShippingInfo(e)' function, but I don't know where to put it, or what else is needed to make it work.

In the meantime, I need to get this form submission done and have tried everything I can think of. Any guidance / help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: `useSelector` is a hook. The 2nd [rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) (you can google 'rule of hooks') is to call them from the top level of React functional components. You haven't posted a ton of context here, but I can certainly tell that the callback function that you're passing to `createAsyncThunk` probably isn't the top level of a React functional component. Is there any other way you can think of to get authToken before the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this issue:

**1. Passing jwt token to thunk action**

**Component**

```
 const  authToken = useSelector(selectJwtToken)

 function handleSaveShippingInfo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // many form fields taken from e.target and assigned to variables
   
        dispatch(saveAddress({ ...list of form variables, authToken }));
    }
```

**thunk**

```
export const saveAddress = createAsyncThunk (
    'addresses/saveAddress',
    async ( props, thunkAPI ) => {
        const { list of form variables, authToken  } = props;     
        let theApiUrl = API_BASE_URL + '/api/v1/address'
```

**2. Get store state from thunkAPI**

```
export const saveAddress = createAsyncThunk (
    'addresses/saveAddress',
    async ( props, {getState} ) => {
        const { list of form variables  } = props;     
        let theApiUrl = API_BASE_URL + '/api/v1/address'
        const authToken = selectJwtToken(getState());
```

Comment: wowo... #2 is what I was imagining, but I didn't know you could use a select that way (with the getState(), I mean). This is the missing piece that totally helped solve the problem. THANK YOU :)